# How can i create a new column that inserts the cell value of grouped column 'ID' (in time) when 'interaction' is 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, iteration

I have three relevant columns: time, id, and interaction.
How can i create a new column with the id values that have a '1' in column 'interaction' in the given time window?

Should look something like this:

```
time   id   vec_len  quadrant   interaction    Paired with

1    3271    0.9    7   0 
1    3229    0.1    0   0
1    4228    0.5    0   0
1    2778   -0.3    5   0
2    4228    0.2    0   0
2    3271    0.1    6   0
2    3229    -0.7   5   1    [2778, 4228]
2    3229    -0.3   2   0
2    4228    -0.8   5   1    [2778, 3229]
2    2778   -0.6    5   1    [4228, 3229]
3    4228    0.2    0   0
3    3271    0.1    6   0
3    4228    -0.7   5   1    [3271]
3    3229    -0.3   2   0
3    3271    -0.8   5   1    [4228]
```

Thank you for helping!!

Comment: What do you mean by "_How can i create a new column with the id values_"? Do you want to add a column to this dataframe or what is your goal?

Comment: i tried to clarify in the title. So in the time block x, when 'interaction' is 1, insert the other id's cell values that also have '1' in that time block into a new column.

Comment: Could you provide an example? All id's are already inside a column `id`. So you want another column `id_interaction` that has the `id` if `interaction` is `1` or `None` otherwise?

Comment: Soory for not being clear enough. I try. So based on time block 2, we have 3 IDs that state 1 in column 'interaction'. In a new column 'Paired with', I would like to list the IDs in that time block that also have 1 in column interaction.

Comment: In this case, 3229 gets the values 2778 and 4228 in a new column, because they also have 'interaction'==1 in time block 2.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

# initialize dict for all time blocks
dict_time_ids = dict.fromkeys(df.time.unique(), set())

# populate dictionary with ids for each time block where interaction == 1
dict_time_ids.update(df.query('interaction == 1').groupby('time').id.apply(set).to_dict())

# make new column with set of corresponding ids where interaction == 1
df['paired'] = np.where(df.interaction == 1, df.time.apply(lambda x: dict_time_ids[x]), set())

# remove the id from the set and convert to list
df.paired = df.apply(lambda x: list(x.paired - {x.id}), axis=1)

# Out:
    time    id  interaction        paired
0      1  3271            0            []
1      1  3229            0            []
2      1  4228            0            []
3      1  2778            0            []
4      2  4228            0            []
5      2  3271            0            []
6      2  3229            1  [2778, 4228]
7      2  3229            0            []
8      2  4228            1  [2778, 3229]
9      2  2778            1  [4228, 3229]
10     3  4228            0            []
11     3  3271            0            []
12     3  4228            1        [3271]
13     3  3229            0            []
14     3  3271            1        [4228]
```